# Parent parent selector nested in stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to get the parent selector in Stylus when it is nested inside a pseudo-selector. So while I can do `&-image` in the first nesting, I can't seem to get it working inside the `&:hover`

```
.post-news
  &-image
    display: none
  &:hover
    &-image // this isn't working
      display: block
```

I understand why it is not working because the `&` doesn't refer to `.post-news` anymore. I tried the selectors listed here http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html such as:

```
../-image
/-image
^[0]-image
```

But I couldn't get it working so far; I'm not sure which one I need. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my understanding, the final selector that you are looking for is `.post-news:hover .post-news-image` and if that is correct, you can do it like in the below snippet.

```
.post-news
  &-image
    display: none
  &:hover
    & ^[0]-image
      display: block
```

When it comes to Stylus, I am a beginner myself but as per my understanding the reason why `^[0]-image` and `../-image` doesn't work as expected is because the Stylus compiler treats them as some sort of a move one level up command and so it effectively becomes the same as the `&-image` which is directly under `.post-news`. Because of this, the normal nesting behavior (which is, for the `.post-news:hover` to be added in front of the nested selector) is not happening. Adding a `&` explicitly seems to address this.